# Chat bots with YouTube Live API

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add YouTube live streams to my custom chat bot. The 10k limit isn't even enough for a 2 hour stream.

Does anyone know how to get around this or know of another way to do chat bots for live streams on YouTube. The other platforms all have WebSockets to listen to events.

Thanks,

Comment: If I remember correctly [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) [LiveChatMessages: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) endpoint costs one quota per call. For a two hours stream that is about 7,200 seconds, with your default 10,000 default quota, you can retrieve new messages more than once a second, isn't it enough in your case? If not then, you can only [request additional quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I tested the quota recently.  I asked for id, author, and snippet.  That cost 5 quota.  At 1 poll per second (roughly) 1 hour, or 3600 seconds is 18K.  EDIT - Additionally, getting the broadcastId takes, I think 10 points.

Comment: @DarrenHoehna I just saw [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76973774).

Comment: Can't re-re-edit my comment.  Did another test, in case anyone else looks at this.  I tried without `id` the cost is still 5 quota.  Seems like the ping is locked at 5. @BenjaminLoison Thank you for answering.