# Do live messages have a push notification?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a bot for youtube that I turn on when I stream.  According to the [LiveMessage documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) part of the response is how long to wait before the bot requests the list again.

Usually this value is slightly over 1000.  If the bot pings the server for a list of messages once every second and a list call is 5 quota(s) and I stream for an hour and a half, I would use 27000 quota.  Over double the limit.

Of course, I might be polling youtube incorrectly.  Here is what I am doing.

1. Send a GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId={LiveChatId}&part=id,authordetails,snippet&access_token={MyAccessToken}`
2. Save `pollingIntervalMillis`, and `nextPageToken`
3. `Task.Delay(MillisecondsToWait)`
4. Make a GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId={LiveChatId}&part=id,authordetails,snippet&access_token={MyAccessToken}&pageToken={nextPageToken}`
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the response has the attribute offlineAt

Looking at [the Java sample](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/live/ListLiveChatMessages.java#L126) this approach is correct.  Just, that the Java example uses a youtube object.

How am I supposed to stay under the 10K limit if I use 5 quota points every second?

Comment: Honestly there are three solutions: 1. [request more quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) 2. webscrap the live chat (I don't remember if [my webscraping endpoint](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/f02e025bff6a38b40331611d97c03e82adc9701a/liveChats.php) still works) 3. use the no-key endpoint I propose on https://yt.lemnoslife.com

Comment: Interesting.  I thought requesting a higher quota was for super-professional bots, or companies.  I'll take a look at all three of your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I opened this issue to investigate [my webscraping endpoint](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/196).

Comment: To anyone looking at this and the only solution is to ping youtube.  As long as your stream isn't getting too many messages, to reduce the amount of API calls multiply milliseconds to wait by 6. That comes out to roughly 4500 points per hour and a half.